# FirewallD not loading rule after reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, firewalld, firewall-cmd

I have FirewallD on Ubuntu Server 18.04. Got allowed services ssh http ipsec.

But on reboot, firewall always allow ssh, ipsec but block http.

To solve this, I have to run `firewall-cmd --reload` every time I boot server.

Where can be problem?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `--permanent`:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=whatever --add-service=http
```

Comment: I have it as permanent rule. If I run firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all after restart, HTTP is listed in services. But the rule is not loaded and HTTP is not accessible. HTTP is accessible after running --reload.